# Why can't I get an error information when I convert a Long value to Int value in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I use Code A to open a activity and pass a long value to parameter id.

I use Code B to get the value of parameter id, but I make a mistaken carelessness to using the code  `var myid =intent.extras.getInt("id")`, and It should be  `var myid =intent.extras.getLong("id")`

The system return an error value 0 for the parameter myid when I use `var myid =intent.extras.getInt("id")`, it cause me to debug the program again and again.

I think that the system should display an error information when I use `var myid =intent.extras.getInt("id")`, but the system give me an error value 0

**Code A**

```
startActivity<UIAddEditBackup>("id" to 2L)
```

**Code B**

```
class UIAddEditBackup: AppCompatActivity() { 
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_add_edit_backup)      

        var myid =intent.extras.getInt("id")
        toast("This is my ID "+myid)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`intent.extras.getInt("id")` will return 0 as default value if it doesn't find any integer value with the same key.

If you want your own default value, then you can use `intent.extras.getInt("id", yourDefValue)`

There could be one more doubt asking why the long can't be casted into integer and return back. The simple answer for this is extras in Intent is nothing but an `ArrayMap<String, Object>`. So whenever we ask for an integer with `getInt(key)`, it tries to do below operations:

```
1. Fetch the value using the given key.
2. Is the key exists?
3. No -> return 0 as default value
4. Yes -> Cast the value to `java.lang.Integer` and return the value
5. In case Casting fails, catch the ClassCastException and return default value (which is 0 in your case)
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think that system should return an error information when it can't find a long value, you know that this incorrect value spend me many time to debug

Comment: I don't assign a default value using intent.extras.getInt("id", yourDefValue), I get an incorrect value  when I use intent.extras.getInt("id")

Comment: so I think that intent.extras.getInt("id", yourDefValue) can return a default value when  it doesn't find any integer value with the same key.

Comment: but  intent.extras.getInt("id") should display an error information when it doesn't find any integer value with the same key.